# What is the relation between binary quadratic forms and quadratic orders?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, quadratic-forms

Quadratic forms are functions $f(X,Y)$ that can be written as $aX^2+bXY+cY^2$ with integer coeficients. Quadratic orders are subrings of finite index of the ring of integers in a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

The 1986 article "Nonsingular Plane Cubic Curves over Finite Fields" by Schoof mentions that the number of equivalence classes for binary quadratic forms and of quadratic orders.

[image]

The definition of $\Delta(\mathcal{O})$ doesn't appear in the text. What is $\Delta(\mathcal{O})$, and how does it relate to the discriminant of a binary form?

Comment: Probably the discriminant of the order $\cal O$.

Comment: I think so, but i can't figure out what is the relation between the two. If an order were to be somehow equivalent to a binary form it would be clear.

Comment: you want Def. 5.2.7 on page 228 of Henri Cohen, A Course in Computational  Number Theory.  For that matter, section 5.2 is called Ideals and Quadratic Forms. There is also a new book by Lehman where everything is done side by side through the book

Comment: https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary quadratic form, with integer coefficients, is some
$$  f(x,y) = A x^2 + B xy + C y^2. $$ The discriminant is
$$ \Delta = B^2 - 4 A C.  $$
We will abbreviate this by $$ \langle A,B,C  \rangle.  $$ It is primitive if $\gcd(A,B,C)=1. $
Standard fact, hard to discover but easy to check: $$  (A x^2 + B x y + C D y^2 )  (C z^2 + B z w + A D w^2 ) = A C X^2 + B X Y + D Y^2,$$ 
where $ X = x z - D yw, \; Y = A xw + C yz + B yw.  $  This gives us Dirichlet's definition of "composition" of quadratic forms of the same discriminant,
$$   \langle A,B,CD  \rangle \circ  \langle C,B,AD  \rangle =  \langle AC,B,D  \rangle. $$ In particular, if this $D=1,$ the result represents $1$ and is ($SL_2 \mathbf Z$) equivalent to the "principal" form for this discriminant.  Oh, duplication or squaring in the group; if $\gcd(A,B)=1,$
$$   \langle A,B,AD  \rangle^2  =  \langle A^2,B,D  \rangle. $$
This comes up with positive forms: $   \langle A,B,C  \rangle \circ  \langle A,-B,C  \rangle =  \langle 1,B,AC  \rangle $ is principal, the group identity. 
Probably should display some $SL_2 \mathbf Z$ equivalence rules, these are how we calculate when things are not quite right for Dirichlet's rule:
 $$    \langle A,B,C  \rangle \cong    \langle C,-B,A  \rangle,  $$
 $$    \langle A,B,C  \rangle \cong    \langle A, B + 2 A, A + B +C  \rangle,  $$
 $$    \langle A,B,C  \rangle \cong    \langle A, B - 2 A, A - B +C  \rangle.  $$

Imaginary first. Suppose we want to know about $\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-47}).$ Reduced positive forms $ \langle A,B,C  \rangle  $ obey $|B| \leq A \leq C$ and $B \neq -A,$ also whenever $A=C$ we have $B \geq 0.$ Our group of binary forms is

```
-47
  class  number  5
 all  
( 1, 1, 12)
( 2, -1, 6)
( 2, 1, 6)
( 3, -1, 4)
( 3, 1, 4)
```

This is an abelian group in any case, so it is cyclic of order 5. These are also the five elements in the ring of integers of  $\mathbf Q(\sqrt {-47}).$
Here is the mapping from forms to ideals: given $ \langle A,B,C  \rangle,  $ drop the letter $C.$ That's it. 
$$  \langle A,B,C  \rangle \mapsto \left[ A, \frac{B + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right].   $$ 
Oh, why is this an ideal, rather than just some $\mathbf Z$-lattice? Because, given $\alpha,\beta$ rational  integers, $$  \left[ \alpha, \frac{\beta + \sqrt \Delta}{2} \right]  $$ is an ideal if and only if
$$ 4 \alpha | ( \Delta - \beta^2 ).  $$

Group: we already see how to do
$$   \langle 2,1,6  \rangle^2  \cong  \langle 4,1,3  \rangle \cong  \langle 3,-1,4  \rangle; $$
$$   \langle 2,1,6  \rangle \circ  \langle 3,-1,4  \rangle  \cong  \langle 2,5,9   \rangle \circ  \langle 3,5,6  \rangle \cong  \langle 6,5,3  \rangle  \cong  \langle 3,-5,6  \rangle \cong  \langle 3,1,4  \rangle; $$
$$   \langle 2,1,6  \rangle \circ  \langle 3,1,4  \rangle  \cong  \langle 6,1,2  \rangle  \cong  \langle 2,-1,6  \rangle.    $$ 
$$   \langle 2,1,6  \rangle \circ  \langle 2,-1,6  \rangle  \cong  \langle 1,1,12 \rangle $$
in any case.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+ \sqrt{-47}}{2}]$ the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-47})$? I'm missing something? This doesn't have five elements. EDIT: just saw your comment on the source